# How can I use console logging in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, console, firebug

Is there a console logger for IE? I'm trying to log a bunch of tests/assertions to the console but I can't do this in IE.

Comment: watch out! `console.log()` only works when IE's dev tool is open (yes IE is crappy). see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742781/why-javascript-only-works-after-opening-developer-tools-in-ie-once

Comment: use cross-browser wrapper: https://github.com/MichaelZelensky/log.js

Answer (score 149, accepted):

You can access IE8 script console by launching the "Developer Tools" (F12). Click the "Script" tab, then click "Console" on the right.

From within your JavaScript code, you can do any of the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log('some msg');
    console.info('information');
    console.warn('some warning');
    console.error('some error');
    console.assert(false, 'YOU FAIL');
</script>
```

Also, you can clear the Console by calling `console.clear()`.

**NOTE:** It appears you must launch the Developer Tools first then refresh your page for this to work.

Comment: This is only for IE8+, but it's a damn fine console. It's basically a replica of Firebug, missing a few features with some other ones thrown in. Search MSDN for it.

Comment: Ah, even though it falls short of Firebug, it still has just enough of what I need. Thanks!

Comment: Link to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565625(v=vs.85).aspx#consolelogging)

Comment: Please note that in IE, unlike in Firefox, if the developer tools are not active, window.console is undefined and calling `console.log()` will break. Always protect your calls with `window.console && console.log('stuff');`

Comment: In case anyone still can't find it, don't do what I did and try to type your script in the top portion of the window: the input area is actually a text area/bar at the bottom of the Developer Tools Console window.

Answer (score 24):

Since version 8, Internet Explorer has its own console, like other browsers. However, if the console is not enabled, the `console` object does not exist and a call to `console.log` will throw an error.

Another option is to use [log4javascript](http://log4javascript.org/) (full disclosure: written by me), which has its own logging console that works in all mainstream browsers, including IE >= 5, plus a wrapper for the browser's own console that avoids the issue of an undefined `console`.

Comment: Hah.. A couple of months I wrote something similar. Good job on that!

Comment: @Tim Down there is a workaround for it http://stackoverflow.com/a/13817235/3057246

Answer (score 16):

### Extremely important if using console.log() in production:

if you end up releasing `console.log()` commands to production you need to put in some kind of fix for IE - because `console` is only defined when in `F12` debugging mode.

```
if (typeof console == "undefined") {
    this.console = { log: function (msg) { alert(msg); } };
}
```

*[obviously remove the alert(msg); statement once you've verified it works]*

See also ['console' is undefined error for Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326650/console-is-undefined-error-for-internet-explorer) for other solutions and more details

Answer (score 9):

There is [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) which gives a lot of Firebug functionality in IE.

Answer (score 5):

Simple IE7 and below shim that preserves Line Numbering for other browsers:

```
/* console shim*/
(function () {
    var f = function () {};
    if (!window.console) {
        window.console = {
            log:f, info:f, warn:f, debug:f, error:f
        };
    }
}());
```

Answer (score 4):

In his book, "Secrets of Javascript Ninja", John Resig (creator of jQuery) has a really simple code which will handle cross-browser console.log issues. He explains that he would like to have a log message which works with all browsers and here is how he coded it:

```
function log() {
  try {
    console.log.apply(console, arguments);
  } catch(e) {
  try {
    opera.postError.apply(opera, arguments);
  }
  catch(e) {
    alert(Array.prototype.join.call( arguments, " "));
  }
}
```

Comment: It's John Resig; you wrote "Resign", LOL

Comment: There is a ```}``` missing in that snippet. :)

Comment: For IE quirks mode, replace console.log line with: `Function.prototype.apply.call(console.log, console, arguments);`

Answer (score 2):

For IE8 or console support limited to console.log (no debug, trace, ...) you can do the following:

- If console OR console.log undefined: Create dummy functions for
  console functions (trace, debug, log, ...)

  `window.console = {
        debug : function() {}, ...};`
- Else if console.log is defined (IE8) AND console.debug (any other) is not defined: redirect all logging functions to console.log, this allows to keep those logs !

  `window.console = {
            debug : window.console.log, ...};`

Not sure about the assert support in various IE versions, but any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cross-browser wrapper: https://github.com/MichaelZelensky/log.js

Answer (score 0):

For older version of IE (before IE8), it is not straight forward to see the console log in IE Developer Toolbar, after spending hours research and trying many different solutions, finally, the following toolbar is great tool for me:

- http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/CompanionJS/Installing

The main advantage of this is providing a console for IE6 or IE7, so you can see what are the error (in the console log)

- Note:
- It is free
- screen shot of the toolbar

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've been always doing something like this:

```
var log = (function () {
  try {
    return console.log;
  }
  catch (e) {
    return function () {};
  }
}());
```

and from that point just always use log(...), don't be too fancy using console.[warn|error|and so on], just keep it simple. I usually prefer simple solution then fancy external libraries, it usually pays off.

simple way to avoid problems with IE (with non existing console.log)