# Colorbox Not Loading Variable URL only in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, coldfusion, colorbox

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION 1**

No errors are displaying in the console.  Also this issue is only happening in IE8 on Windows XP.  Windows 7 in IE8 works just fine.

**QUESTION**

I am requesting colorbox to open a complex URL

```
$('.manage_locations').colorbox({
    innerWidth: '1100px',
    innerHeight: '505px',
    iframe:true,
    href:'/admin_console/assignments_groups_group_information_manage_locations.cfm?gid=3&amp;CFID=22701&amp;CFTOKEN=83690449'});
```

This system is built in ColdFusion.  When I click the trigger `.manage_locations` it launches the colorbox, but the loader just spins and never loads the iFrame content.  I have narrowed it down to the issue is the data in the URL after the `?`  Any ideas how I could correct this for IE8?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Make sure you look at the output in the js console, otherwise you're debugging in the dark.

Comment: I think that should read "?gid=3&CFID=22701&CFTOKEN=83690449" if you're passing separate variables.

Comment: I adjusted `&amp;` to `&` but no change was seen in IE8.  How can I view the console in IE8?  I have the developer tools installed, but I don't see a way to view the console within those tools.

Comment: Okay I found how to view the console in IE8 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656730/internet-explorer-console

Comment: I am getting no errors in the console.  Also a new fact I have found is this issue only appears on Windows XP IE8.  Windows 7 IE8 works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was corrected by setting the fastIframe property to false to delay the removal of the loading graphic until the iframe element's onload event fires.  Example:

```
$('a.myIframe').colorbox({iframe:true, width:500, height:500, fastIframe:false});
```

Comment: Thanks so much! The fastIframe property did the trick for me as well.

Comment: Glad it helped you out.  I spent way too much time trying to find a resolution to this problem.  Hopefully it did not hender you as much.