# How to implement a cross browser console.log functionality

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, console.log

Is there a cross browser way of implementing console.log functionality, 
the official supported browser at one of my client is still IE7/IE8.

As development is tested with Firefox for its debugging capabilities, 
often come across issues on release as some obscure flow still left with un commented console.log statements which doesn't fly with IE

looking for kind of, if anybody does use an elegant way, would love to learn.

```
function log(msg){
   if(IE) alert(msg)
   else
     console.log(msg)
}
```

Comment: Just make a fake `console` object if there isn't one already

Comment: Production code generally shouldn't need to output to the console

Comment: Does this help? IE8 [Internet Explorer Console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656730/internet-explorer-console)

Comment: An alternate solution is to run your scripts through a [linter](http://jshint.com/) which will alert you to any `console.log` calls which remain so that you can remove them.

Comment: Obligatory: [What is an XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377)

Comment: @dc5 the question is how to prevent existing `log` calls from bombing the page in IE, not how to view the console in IE.

Comment: @Mathletics - partially correct.  The first part of the question was "Is there a cross browser way of implementing console.log functionality," and IE 8 was mentioned as not supporting it.  Thought that might be information the OP didn't already have.

Comment: why in the world would you want cross-browser console.log??????????????

Comment: Most modern browsers (including IE) has console.log so cross browser version may not be even needed. Drop support for IE8 and you're sorted :).

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option:

```
if (typeof console === "undefined" || typeof console.log === "undefined") {  
    console = {};
    console.log = function(msg) {
        alert(msg);
    };
}
```

EDIT: as noted by others, you really should make sure that console.log doesn't end up in production code.

Comment: I don't necessarily think that console.log is super bad thing on production code. As long as it doesn't break anything some logs like "application loaded", "controler initialized" etc may not be a big deal. unless it breaks stuff, then yeah, it may be a problem.

Comment: @zigdawgydawg This looks promising, i will test it out and accept.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at something like:

[log4javascript](http://log4javascript.org/)

or

[log4js](http://log4js.berlios.de/)

They maybe what you are looking for (there are others too)

Then you can detect if the console object is available on the browser you are using and if not then assign the appropriate functions from those libraries.

Though reading your question, it does seem like an XY problem.

Comment: good to know log library for javascript, i will give it a spin