# How to load tweets on static page

Tags: html, twitter

Reading the [Twitter for developers](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines), I did create new widget in the twitter and then pasted to respective field on my html:

```
  <a class="twitter-timeline"  href="https://twitter.com/paganpride"  data-widget-id="372641761669046272">Tweets by @paganpride</a>
 <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

But everytime I load my page I can jus see the text `Tweets by @paganpride` and not actual tweets.

Do anyone have any idea where I could go wrong?

If you are interested, the page is www.paganpride.cz - in Czech language only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is your domain correctly whitelisted?  Check your javascript console for errors.

UPDATE:  I tried your site and it looks like it's working for me, so either you fixed it, or else you're accessing your site via a different url or something which is causing the domain whitelisting to fail for you.

---

UPDATE 2: this is how it looks for me:

[image: site]

Comment: ok, how do I do it? Can you please edit your response and provide me more info regarding the console<

Comment: Console depends on your browser, but usually F12 works. here's some links: Firefox https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Debugging_JavaScript IE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656730/internet-explorer-console Chrome https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console

Comment: Ah ok, I am sitting behind proxy now. So it could be the explanation. Thanks for help

Comment: it should work behind a proxy so long as you can reach both www.paganpride.cz and twitter.com