# javascript console log not working

Tags: javascript, console.log

I am new to JS. Today I was trying to practice a little of what I've learned, and I can't get my console log to print anything. My "good morning" alert works, as well as my initial prompt question, but once I answer "yes" or "no," everything stops. Here is my code:

```
alert("Good morning!");

var hireMe = prompt("Are you here because you're interested in hiring me?");

if (hireMe === "yes") {
console.log("You've just made my day. Carry on.")
}

else {
    console.log("Well, I hope you're at least thinking about it.")
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is there anything at all printed in the console? What if you replace the alert with a `console.log()`?

Comment: which browser are you using ? not every browser supports console.log

Comment: What's your browser? Any messages in developer's console?

Comment: Have you tried restarting your computer? I kid, I mean browser?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't specify which browser. I am using Chrome. No, I have not tried restarting my browser. Just wanted to be sure that nothing was wrong with my syntax.

Comment: Then this should work...what appears in your console?

Comment: Works fine in Chrome here (aside from weirdness with the `else` due to your extra line breaks).

Comment: @tymeJV - I don't see any console window appear at all. It's as if no more code is written beyond the prompt.

Comment: Jill, you have to open the console on your own, press F12

Comment: @Quentin - thanks. Maybe it's a Chrome issue on my end, perhaps? I'll see if any updates need to be downloaded.

Comment: No problem, be sure to mark @Quentin 's answer

Comment: Also, the console is your best friend when debugging, if you have an issue, check the console first, you'll get all the error messages there. It will save you countless hours!

Comment: @tymeJV - I will remember that about checking the console! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't see any console window appear at all. It's as if no more code is written beyond the prompt

`console.log` will write to the console.

It will **not** cause the console window to open if it isn't already open.

You have to open your browser's console (the Developer Tools since you are using Chrome) manually.

Comment: Thank you. Didn't know I had to do that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers (IE) will crash if the developer tools (F12) are not open:
[How can I use console logging in Internet Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656730/internet-explorer-console)

Comment: It's true, but it's not the cause of the problem above (I didn't vote, but just saying, that's probably it)

Comment: "once I answer "yes" or "no," everything stops."

Comment: It's already been established in the comments that the browser is Chrome.

Comment: It hadn't been at the time this answer was given

Comment: Thank you for answering (I didn't down vote you). :) I didn't receive e-mail notifications for these additional answers (even in my spam), so I apologize that I didn't answer sooner about the browser.

Comment: And my answer was posted before those comments were made.

Comment: "[..]I am using Chrome.[..] – Jill 6 mins ago" vs "answered 5 mins ago". And the answer is still wrong, regardless of when the information came in.

Comment: It takes people time to write answers. The comment almost certainly wasn't displayed when as the answer was composed. The answer is a plausible one.

Answer (score 0):

IE unfortunately has this dependency where the console object gets created only when you open it (F12). So console.log tries to call the log method for the object console, and if that object is not yet created, it results in an error.

Answer (score 0):

In chrome, sometimes the content that can be displayed on the console, can be changed to "Hide All". To view the necessary content, select the appropriate fields in the drop down.

[view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsCJU.png)

Comment: This feature also exists in other browsers. There are also other values that this dropdown can be set to and hide `console.log()` output. Make sure that your browser is displaying the console outputs you need.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your ' if ' statement. It does work with three but it's better to use double equals. Your code will be:

```js
alert("Good morning!");

var hireMe = prompt("Are you here because you're interested in hiring me?");

if (hireMe == "yes") {
console.log("You've just made my day. Carry on.")
}

else {
    console.log("Well, I hope you're at least thinking about it.")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your ' if ' statement. It does work with three but it's better to use double equals. Your code will be:

```js
if (hireMe == "yes") {
console.log("You've just made my day. Carry on.")
}

else {
    console.log("Well, I hope you're at least thinking about it.")
}
```